# passing data between interfacecontrollers not working in apple watch

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

[image: This is the way i have my view controllers]

I was using this code to pass data between controllers.

```
InterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(["1","2","3"], contexts: ["adf","asd","asd"])
```

I called this code in willActivate() method, that you can see here.

```
 override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
        InterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(["1","2","3"], contexts: ["adf","asd","asd"])
    }
```

I have no idea about whats wrong with this code, in apple watch, the app is just refreshing again and again. Is there any other method to pass data between interface controllers while we use page based navigation.??

Answer (score 1):

Please Find the below way of passing data in paged-based navigation in watch application (Watch os 2 and later).

Note :

> An array of strings, each of which contains the name of an interface controller you want to display in the page-based interface. In your storyboard, the name of an interface controller is stored in the object’s Identifier property, which is located in the attributes inspector. The order of the strings in the array is used to set the order of the corresponding interface controllers. This parameter must not be nil or an empty array.

Objectiv C

```
[self presentControllerWithNames:@[@"FirstViewController",@"SecondViewController",@"ThirdViewController"] contexts:@[@"adf",@"asd",@"asd"]];
```

Swift

```
let controller = ["FirstViewController","SecondViewController","ThirdViewController"]
    let pageContexts:[AnyObject]? = ["adf","asd","asd"]

    presentControllerWithNames(controller, contexts: pageContexts)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `reloadRootControllersWithNames(NSArray, contexts: NSArray)` onto the view controller, it will do as the function is titled: `reload.` Therefore, you have a view controller that refreshes all 3 of the items in the first Array you give, and then, since your current `view controller` calls `willActivate()` upon loading, it infinitely refreshes.

I don't have enough reputation to make this a comment, but my suggestion here is to find a method that you can call on an instance of the watch interface you want to in order to pass data.

What I mean is, if you have each interface as its own class, then you can make a method in the interface **you want to get to** that sets a property to whatever data you want to transfer before you present the interface.

I also use Objective-C more than Swift, but here's what my guess is as to what the Obj-C code would come to:

```
SecondWatchInterface *secondWatchInterface = [SecondWatchInterface new];
[SecondWatchInterface setSomeDataWithAStringValue:@"Foo"];
[self presentWatchInterface:SecondWatchInterface]
```

In Swift, I'm thinking this would equate to:

```
SecondWatchInterface *secondWatchInterface = SecondWatchInterface.new()
secondWatchInterface.setSomeDataWithAStringFile:"Foo"
presentWatchInterface(secondWatchInterface)
```

I'm unfamiliar with WatchKit myself; I typically use SpriteKit. I hope I helped identify what the problem was, at least!

Answer (score 0):

To pass data between interface controllers you need to go for this method:

```
presentControllerWithName(“Second Watch Controller”, context: [“segue”:“pagebased”,“data”: "Data Passed Successfully”]);
```

Also, you can refer to this example: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2272657&seqNum=3